# sending email using codeigniter email class

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

i have an error by trying to send an email using codeigniter email Class.

I have an error of :
Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

How can i test to send email in codeigniter?. I am also using localhost. Is this problem only occurs when i use localhost?

Here is my code:

```
public function emailme() {
        $this->load->library('email');
        $message = $this->input->post('email_msg');
        $this->email->from('iamjohnx3303@yahoo.com', 'John');
        $this->email->to('iamjohnx3302@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->send();
    }
```

Comment: https://www.codexworld.com/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-in-php/

Comment: @dhruvjadia thanks for your reply, i want to use codeigniter library Email Class. Is there any wrong method in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuration in **sendmail.ini**

path   `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`

Configurations

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=yourgmailpassword
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
```

in **php.ini**

path`c:\xampp\xampp\php\php.ini`

```
[mail function]
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

then

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com',// your mail name
'smtp_pass' => '*****',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
 'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

### **Mail Settings in XAMPP(Important)**

```
$this->email->from('mygmail@gmail.com', 'myname');//your mail address and name
$this->email->to('target@gmail.com'); //receiver mail

$this->email->subject('testing');
$this->email->message($message);

$this->email->send(); //sending mail
```

Comment: i'll try ur answer sir, and reply immediately

Comment: also, change settings in your gmail to the Allowing less secure apps to access your account

Answer (score 1):

Use this before your send mail script

```
// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.yourdomain.com.
ini_set("SMTP","mail.YourDomain.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","25");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'ValidEmailAccount@YourDomain.com');
```

Comment: Interesting! this maintains the originality of php.ini rather than modifying it every time